# Quando usar mim ou eu

Tags: gramática, pronomes, frases

Na seguinte frase,

> Ele é mais novo do que eu.

poderia acontecer a seguinte mudança?

> Ele é mais novo do que mim.

Em relação a construção que precede o pronome, seria mais culto

> Ele é mais novo que *pronome* ou Ele é mais novo do que *pronome*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

O correto é *Ele é mais novo do que eu* ou *Ele é mais novo que eu*. Isso porque o *eu* pode ser usado como sujeito ou predicativo do sujeito e o *mim* **deve** ser precedido de uma preposição.

#### Pronomes

Antes de mais nada, é preciso entender que os pronomes do caso reto exercem a função de sujeito e predicativo do sujeito.

São pronomes do caso reto:

- Eu;
- Tu;
- Ele / Ela;
- Nós;
- Vós;
- Eles / Elas.

Já os pronomes oblíquos tônicos exercem a função de objeto indireto e são **sempre** precedido de uma preposição como *para*, *com*, *de* etc.

São pronomes oblíquos tônicos:

- Mim;
- Ti;
- Si;
- Nos;
- Vos;
- Eles / Elas / Si

Podemos observar que é incorreto utilizar "do que mim" (no exemplo dado), mas continuemos.

#### Análise Gramatical

Na frase *Ele é mais novo do que eu*, possuímos duas orações:

- Ele é mais novo;
- Do que eu (sou)

> Atenção! O verbo *ser* está subentendido/implícito

Para encontrar o sujeito de cada oração, devemos perguntar aos verbos *é* e *sou*, respectivamente, *quem é?* e *quem sou?*. Dessa forma encontraremos o sujeito *ele* e *eu*. Logo o correto é *ele é mais novo do que eu (sou)*, já que o pronome *mim* não pode ser usado como sujeito de uma oração e **deve** ser precedido de uma preposição.

> Observação: Alguns podem achar que *do que* seja uma preposição, mas na verdade é uma conjunção. Fica a Dica.

#### Grau comparativo dos adjetivos

De acordo com o gramático Evanildo Bechara, *"O [grau] Comparativo compara qualidade entre dois ou mais seres, estabelecendo:*

- *Igualdade;*
- *Superioridade; e*
- *Inferioridade."*

Em todos esses casos, tanto faz utilizar *quanto*, *como* (para igualdade), *que* ou *do que* (para os demais).

> O rapaz é tão cuidadoso *quanto* os outros.
> O rapaz é tão cuidadoso *como* os outros.
>
> O rapaz é mais cuidadoso *do que* os outros.
> O rapaz é mais cuidadoso *que* os outros.
>
> O rapaz é menos cuidadoso *do que* os outros.
> O rapaz é menos cuidadoso *que os* outros.

[Fonte](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/7647.md)

Comment: "*sempre precedido de uma preposição como para, com, de etc.*   Essa noção é que faz com que muitos brasileiros incidam no erro ao dizer "empresta aqui pra mim ver", "Me dá um pedaço pra mim provar"

Comment: @Centaurus Assim como tantas outras regras da língua portuguesa, essa (mim x eu) é bem "complicada". De fato, os pronomes tônicos são precedidos de uma preposição, mas algumas pessoas acabam não percebendo/tendo ciência) que um determinado verbo pede o sujeito (o que impede o uso do mim). Outra noção que faz com que muitos brasileiros incidam no erro é afirmar que o correto é "pra eu provar", "pra eu ver" com a explicação que o *mim* não conjuga verbo. Claro que não conjuga, mas no Português, são raros os casos que podemos considerar o *sempre* como resposta; e sem olhar o o contexto.

Comment: Valdeir, não entendi essa parte do seu comentário; *Outra noção que faz com que muitos brasileiros incidam no erro é afirmar que o correto é "pra eu provar", "pra eu ver"*    Afirmar que o correto é "pra eu ver" faz com que as pessoas incidam no erro ?

Comment: @Centaurus O comentário é porque vejo mais pessoas afirmando que "pra mim ver", "pra mim estudar", "pra mim fazer" é incorreto e ponto (não foi relacionado ao seu comentário, mas peguei os exemplos para tentar facilitar a compreensão). A depender do contexto, o "pra mim ver" estará correto, isso acontece bastante com sujeitos oracionais deslocado: "É difícil para mim estudar gramática" -> "Estudar gramática é difícil para mim"; "Foi difícil para mim fazer isso" -> "Fazer isso foi difícil para mim". +

Comment: Óbvio que alguns professores discordam ou fala que o uso da vírgula seria obrigatório nestes casos, enfim... Acho que daria uma boa pergunta.

Comment: Valdeir,  é exatamente o que eu ia mencionar, a vírgula.na língua escrita.  ex;  Pra mim, estudar chinês mandarim não teria nenhuma utilidade.

Answer (score 3):

A resposta correta é "Ele é mais novo do que eu".

As duas hipóteses - para eu e para mim - existem na língua portuguesa e estão corretas. Contudo, devem ser usadas em situações diferentes.

A expressão para eu deverá ser usada quando assume a função de sujeito:

para eu fazer;
para eu ler;
para eu aprender;
para eu estudar;
para eu ir;
…
A expressão para mim deverá ser usada quando assume a função de objeto indireto:

fez para mim;
ligou para mim;
perguntou para mim;
comprou para mim;
sorriu para mim;
…
Sendo eu um pronome pessoal reto e mim um pronome pessoal oblíquo tônico.

Comment: Sim, mas porquê? Acho que sem essa explicação, a resposta fica fraca.

Comment: @CIMend, obrigado pela resposta. Como o(a) ANeves disse, gostaria de uma explicação "técnica" para construir outras frases corretamente.

Comment: Só ter cuidado com o *para eu estudar*, por exemplo, que também pode ser "para mim estudar" (dependendo do contexto)

Comment: Ficou ótima, a resposta. Obrigado pela edição. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regrinha de ouro para resumir: nunca utilize "mim" para conjugar um verbo. Mantendo isso em mente, fica fácil.

Comment: Como é que isso ajuda no exemplo dado na pergunta? Não me parece que "mim" esteja a conjugar nenhum verbo: "Ele é mais novo do que mim."